# Multiply the elements of nested array by its depth and output a sum

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a nested array

```
[1,2,4,[2,6,[3,2],4],7]
```

Now the output array should be `[1,2,4,4,12,9,6,8,7]` where each element is the output of  `element * depth of array`;

and now getting the sum of elements of array would give `53`

I have implemented a recursive method as below

```
    let level = 1
    let sum = 0
    function recursive(arr){
     arr.forEach(i=> {
       multiplier(i)
     })
    }
    function multiplier(i){
     if(Array.isArray(i)){
       level++
       recursive(i);
       
     } else {
          sum += i*level 
       }
    }
```

What am i doing wrong here? How can I control the variable level ?

Comment: `level` should better be a parameter, not a global. Also `sum` should better not be global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You copuld take a single function which gets the array and possible known depth and return the total.

```js
const
    data = [1, 2, 4, [2, 6, [3, 2], 4], 7],
    sum = (data, depth = 1) => {
        let total = 0;
        for (const value of data) {
            total += Array.isArray(value)
                ? sum(value, depth + 1)
                : value * depth;
        }
        return total;
    },
    result = sum(data);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue lies in using the global variable `level` to track the depth of the nested array, which may lead to interference with other calls. You should pass the current `level` as a parameter to the recursive function and utilize that value to calculate the multiplier, ensuring that each recursive call maintains its own `level` and avoiding unintended side effects.

**Demo:**

```js
let sum = 0;

function recursive(arr, level) {
  arr.forEach((i) => {
    multiplier(i, level);
  });
}

function multiplier(i, level) {
  if (Array.isArray(i)) {
    recursive(i, level + 1);
  } else {
    sum += i * level;
  }
}

const inputArray = [1, 2, 4, [2, 6, [3, 2], 4], 7];
recursive(inputArray, 1);

console.log(sum); //53
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not decrementing the level variable when you exit from a nested array.
and also not resetting the level variable properly when you start processing a new array.

```js
let sum = 0;

function recursive(arr, level) {
    arr.forEach(i => {
        multiplier(i, level);
    });
}

function multiplier(i, level) {
    if (Array.isArray(i)) {
        recursive(i, level + 1);
    } else {
        sum += i * level;
    }
}

// Test
let array = [1, 2, 4, [2, 6, [3, 2], 4], 7];
recursive(array, 1);
console.log(sum); // Output should be 53
```

Now, `recursive` function takes an additional argument `level` which represents the current depth of the array. When you encounter a nested array, you pass `level + 1` to the recursive call. When you exit from a nested array, you don't need to decrement level since it's passed by value and not by reference.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to have two separate functions. Just write a single `recursiveSum` or whatever you want to name it, and walk through the input.

```js
function recursiveSum(arr, level=1) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (const el of arr) {
        if (Array.isArray(el)) {
            sum += recursiveSum(el, level + 1);
        } else {
            // You might want to check that `el` is actually
            // a number here, just to be safe.
            sum += el * level;
        }
    }

    return sum;
}

let array = [1, 2, 4, [2, 6, [3, 2], 4], 7];
console.log(recursiveSum(array));
```

This has the advantage that it doesn't depend on global variables. It doesn't mutate the input array either. It's a pure function without side effects.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```js
function traverseImpl(arrInput, depth, arrOutput) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (index in arrInput) {
        var item = arrInput[index]
        if (typeof(item) === 'number') {
            sum += item*depth;
            arrOutput.push(item * depth)
        } else if (typeof(item) === 'object') {
            sum += traverseImpl(item, depth+1, arrOutput)
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

function traverse(arrInput) {
    var arrOutput = []
    var sum = traverseImpl(arrInput,1,arrOutput)
    return {arrOutput, sum};
}

var result = traverse([1,2,4,[2,6,[3,2],4],7]);
console.log(result.arrOutput);
console.log(result.sum);
```